# Requesting for new password in domaintools.com, when my account is not active

Tags: password-recovery

After some time, I'm back to [domaintools.com](http://domaintools.com/). When I want to get a new password, and I enter my email address, I get the following message:

> The account associated with this email address is not active

OK, what to do now? There is not a help or anyway to reactivate my account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [submit a Support Ticket](http://support.domaintools.com/), or email `memberservices@domaintools.com` so we can properly address your issue.

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here.